# Gltf2 Java Viewer

Tags: java, android, view, model, gltf

I'm making an app in Android studio and can't display gltf2 model in SceneView(without AR), i'm tried a lot of projects and samples, but they doesn't work. Anybody know how display GLTF2 models in Android studio/Java?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In solution i started using scenform(sceneview for no ar) and went to .glb format, that works good with firebase
Problem of using .gltf file format in firebase storage is that? the couldn't load the .bin file from firebase database

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).